# Is it required to register with the Red Hat Subscription Manager while using centos7to install undercloud?

Tags: openstack, tripleo

### If No then

- how relevant repositories will be subscribed?
- Updates will be Performed

### Details

- What I am trying to do?

  I am trying to create our personal OpenStack cloud and install one undercloud node in VirtualBox, and I have a server blade in which I want to provision My OverCloud Nodes
  p.s. All the requirements are fulfilled in the context of machine specifications
- Why Did I ask this Question?

  I am trying to deploy an undercloud node for days with the below-given configurations

  ```
   [DEFAULT]
   local_interface = enp0s8
   local_mtu = 1500
   local_ip = 192.168.0.105/24
   generate_service_certificate = true
   enable_ui = true
   undercloud_debug = true

   [ctlplane-subnet]
   cidr = 192.168.0.0/24
   gateway = 192.168.0.105
   dhcp_start = 192.168.0.120
   dhcp_end = 192.168.0.140
  ```

  So my question is if I don't use subscription-manager What will be the impact is this the main reason that I am getting errors for days. The last error which I had is for the task
  ***Output for sync deployment HostsEntryDeployment*** and the error which I am receiving is

  ```
     1) /usr/libexec/os-refresh-config/configure.d/55-heat-config: No 
        such file or directory
     2) jq: error: Could not open file /var/lib/heat- 
        config/deployed/aa6e0893-386f-4f09-9a77- 
        077275ea6198.notify.json: No such file or directory
  ```

### Update

Just to resolve the first error I have to copy the file from [55-heat-config](https://github.com/openstack/heat-agents/blob/master/heat-config/os-refresh-config/configure.d/55-heat-config) and then change add the execution mode to the permissions of the file. I am wondering a lot of things I had to do myself. So either the newer OpenStack is buggy or My centos7 has a lot of problems which is not possible just by looking at the nature of the problems I am facing.

Comment: You don't need a Red Hat subscription when using Centos. In fact, I doubt you can install subscription manager on Centos. You will use Centos repositories, which don't require subscription. The cause of your error is something else.

Comment: That is great, Not having a clue how to solve this error.